# to highlight the first block in the dropdown list during searching

Tags: search, gwt

I want to have the searching event like the google+.As when we search the friend then the first block get highlighted and when we enter the key, its value comes in the textbox.I have achieved upto the searching of the value and make the letter italic which is being type.

```
   public class AlphaKeyPress implements KeyUpHandler
{
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) 
    {
        String ab =textbox.getText();

        if(ab.length()>0)
        {
            greetingService.server(ab,new AsyncCallback<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
                {
                    Window.alert("Invalid");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("At the client side..."+result);

                    if(result.isEmpty())
                    { 
                        System.out.println("result");

                        p.clear();

                        Label lii = new Label("not found");

                        p.setVisible(true);
                        p.setBorderWidth(1);
                        p.add(lii);

                        RootPanel.get().add(p);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p.clear();
                        p.setVisible(false);
                        p.setVisible(true);
                        p.setBorderWidth(1);

                        int l=0;
                        int count=0;

                        for (String retval: result.split("/"))
                        {
                            String match=textbox.getText();
                            String html = retval.replace(match, "<b><i>" + match + "</i></b>");

                            final HTML htm=new HTML(html);

                            htm.setStyleName("green");  

                            if(retval.contains(match))
                            {
                                if(l==0)
                                {
                                    htm.setHTML(html);
                                    if(count==0)
                                    {
                                        htm.addStyleName("add");
                                        count++;
                                    }
                                    else



                                    p.add(htm);

                                    l++;


                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    htm.setHTML(html);

                                    p.add(htm);

                                    l--;
                                }
                            }
                            RootPanel.get().add(p);

                            htm.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
                            {
                                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
                                {
                                    String str=htm.getText();
                                    textbox.setText(str);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }   
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over the results, instead of doing  `for (String retval: result.split("/"))` , you can do:

```
String[] results = title.split("/");
for (int i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
  if (i==0) {
    //add result with highlighted html
  } else {
    //add result normally
  }
}
```

If you want to have an idea about the html, just click on the right button on Google+, then "Inspect element".

UPDATE (based on comments):

For adding mouse over controls, just follow the same path that you have done with the ClickHandler:

```
htm.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
    //add your css
  }
});

htm.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {

  @Override
  public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
    // remove your css        
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you but i want to remove or set css on mouse over event.?

Comment: sorry but its not working in it,i want searching just as in google+.my first block of txt below the textbox by default highlighted but if we move the mouse over the blocks of text or press arrow key then css also move and when stop moving mouse or stop arrow key pressing,then css stick over the last block....

Comment: and as well as if we press enter key then then highlighted data move or copy the text from the block into the textbox